# Sequelize error: "Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually" even when my dialect is "mysql"

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am getting this error on running my nodejs project
`Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually`

Event i added `mysql` as. dialect in sequelize connection

Here is my server code

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASS, {
 host: process.env.DB_HOST,
 port: process.env.DB_PORT,
 dialect: 'mysql'
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
app.listen(port, () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
}).catch((error) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(error);
  throw Error('Error in db connect');
});
```

Here is code of package.json file

```
{
  "name": "geosafe-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "node src/index",
    "format:check": "prettier --check .",
    "format:write": "prettier --write .",
    "lint:check": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ."
 },
 "author": "Vinit Singh",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
   "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
   "express": "^4.18.1",
   "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
   "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
   "passport": "^0.6.0",
   "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
   "sequelize": "^6.21.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^8.23.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
  "prettier": "^2.7.1"
}
}
```

even when i install sqlite3 package i gets table not found error. I this there is some issue in my connection but cannot able to find solution.

Comment: Please provide your package.json file

Comment: @AsifJalil. Added package.json file code

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11174

Comment: @KonradLinkowski That is different issue. I am not using sqlite db. I am using mysql db still getting sqlite error.